# What is the best way to rewrite this repeated if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm thinking there is an easier way to write this code, but not sure on what approach to take. Basically, I want to check if each variable exists, and if so - add the appropriate markup to the page.

Any suggestions would be great.

```
<?php
    $words = get_field('words');
    $photography = get_field('photography');
    $architect = get_field('architect');
?>

<div class="panel">
    <?php if( $words ): ?>
        <div>
            <p><span>Words</span><span><?php echo $words;?></span></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif ;?>

    <?php if( $photography ): ?>
        <div>
            <p><span>Photography</span><span><?php echo $photography;?></span></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if( $architect ): ?>
        <div>
            <p><span>Architect</span><span><?php echo $architect;?></span></p>
       </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: how about using `elseif`s? or a `switch` statement? it depends if the variables are mutually exclusive, can you have `$words` and `$arcitect`, for instance?

Comment: what `get_field()` returns?

Comment: @b0s3 get_field() returns a string & boolean value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `array` & `loop` -

```
<?php
    $fields = array();
    $fields['words'] = get_field('words');
    $fields['photography'] = get_field('photography');
    $fields['architect'] = get_field('architect');
?>

<div class="panel">
    <?php foreach($fields as $key => $value): 
         if($value)
    ?>
        <div>
            <p><span><?php echo ucwords($key);?></span><span><?php echo $value;?></span></p>
        </div>
    <?php 
         endif;
    endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for your help. Definitely can see myself using this method in the future.

Comment: This is a great answer, as it also improves code _readability_ and _maintainability_.

Comment: @dotancohen *readability and maintainability* is the main concern. :)

Comment: I strongly recommend that organize your function calling like get_field() in a no-repeat way as it may spread out quickly someday.

Answer (score 5):

Create a field array with their appropriate label if you want to have your own labels.

```
<div class="panel">
    <?php
    $fields = array (
            'words' => 'Words',
            'photography' => 'Photography',
            'architect' => 'Architect' 
    );
    foreach ( $fields as $field => $label ) {
        $value = get_field ( $field );
        if (!empty($value)) {
            echo '<div>
                <p><span>' . $label . '</span><span>' . $value . '</span></p>
            </div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `$fields [$field]` should be replaced with  `$field`. And `$field` should be replaced with `get_field ( $field )`. Also if `get_field ( $field )` return `true` for every value then it will not result in expected way.

Comment: Now `$field` should be replaced with `$value` in `span`.

Comment: @ling.s This is really great too. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $required_fields = array("words","photography","architect");
   $data = array();
   foreach($required_fields as $field)
   {
        $data[$field] = get_field($field);
   }
?>


<div class="panel">
    <?php foreach($data as $data_field=>$data_value): 
         if($data_value)
    ?>
        <div>
            <p><span><?=$data_field?></span><span><?=$data_value?></span></p>
        </div>
    <?php 
         endif;
    endforeach ;?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this and then iterate the data that it returns to output your content

```
<?php
    //define a function to fetch data in specific fields
    function fetch_data($keys=array()){
        $data = array();
        foreach($keys as $key){
            $val = get_field($key);
            if(!empty($val)){
                $data[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }

    //now you can easily add or change your fields
    $data = fetch_data(array('words','photography','architect'));
?>

<div class="panel">

<?php 
    foreach($data as $field){
        if(isset($data[$field])){
            $val = $data[$field];
            ?>
            <div>
                <p><span><?php echo ucfirst($field); ?></span><span><?php echo $val; ?></span></p>
            </div>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```